# Issue with merging multiple JSON files in Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to combine multiple JSON files in a Ubuntu platform. As an example, the data from two files are as follows:

**File_1**

```
{
    "artist":"Gob",
    "timestamp":"2011-08-09 01:59:41.352247",
    "similars":[
        [
            "TRTOVWD128F92F4227",
            1
        ],
        [
            "TRUXNUD128F92F41D0",
            0.97294099999999994
        ],
        [
            "TRNNOJO128F42992E9",
            0.073926900000000004
        ],
        [
            "TRGZHTT128F423B2A4",
            0.068387699999999996
        ],
        [
            "TRGYKYD128F42625F6",
            0.065579700000000005
        ],
        [
            "TRGIWHY128F42625F5",
            0.064063700000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRJCJTX128F930CACE",
            0.063140100000000005
        ],
        [
            "TRMYNWT128F426254B",
            0.0613825
        ],
        [
            "TRRQOJI128F428C865",
            0.061121599999999998
        ],
        [
            "TRBNYHM128F428A569",
            0.061121599999999998
        ],
        [
            "TRDLOYE128F4241E72",
            0.060951900000000003
        ],
        [
            "TRNRVEW12903CBA24F",
            0.060332700000000003
        ],
        [
            "TRKKIPG12903CBA083",
            0.060155
        ],
        [
            "TRZHTGP128F428A63B",
            0.059873599999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRKQSGZ128F428A851",
            0.059873599999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRTOPDF128F42AD88A",
            0.059687799999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRIWOPM128F4241E53",
            0.058958900000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRCCJUW128F14652DB",
            0.057935
        ],
        [
            "TRERDDF128F428ECC4",
            0.057566600000000002
        ],
        [
            "TROKWNN128F421A3D8",
            0.057379800000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRWGOOK128F42AE765",
            0.057125000000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRFMNKP128F428ADC0",
            0.056875099999999998
        ],
        [
            "TRDMLZT128F42A01A8",
            0.055808900000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRGCJVM128E0780E48",
            0.0547389
        ],
        [
            "TRRXGAY128F14652D7",
            0.0538065
        ],
        [
            "TRIPEHH128F1462DFF",
            0.052843000000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRDUOIP128F147D5A7",
            0.051851500000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRZCHHD12903CC80A1",
            0.051251699999999997
        ],
        [
            "TRFDDQS128F426243F",
            0.051018300000000003
        ],
        [
            "TRZDKAR128F42591B8",
            0.050740899999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRDVXUG128F1456CBF",
            0.050486299999999998
        ],
        [
            "TRULRYN128F145FC1C",
            0.050219800000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRMOWIA128F425CE0F",
            0.049977500000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRUVPMZ128F42B6DF3",
            0.049762000000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRSBDWW128F4262666",
            0.049643699999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRKPHWQ128F4264F8C",
            0.0495173
        ],
        [
            "TRBBLXU128F42623A1",
            0.049416700000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRJKLLM128F1456C57",
            0.049001599999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRSAAEI128F4216C24",
            0.048813500000000003
        ],
        [
            "TRFXICT128F4264F8A",
            0.048776199999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRINVLH12903CBE5A1",
            0.048334500000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRMUUJR128F4262475",
            0.048306500000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRTORTD128F1456AFA",
            0.0468265
        ],
        [
            "TRECUJO12903CA7120",
            0.046065599999999998
        ],
        [
            "TRXIRBQ128F93431BB",
            0.0456938
        ],
        [
            "TRFDDVK128F42B6DF0",
            0.045623799999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRSRGPM128F421A30B",
            0.043976800000000003
        ],
        [
            "TRVUPPR128F429507D",
            0.042872500000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRMHCZC128F428A4CD",
            0.040675200000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRUFDRV128F4262352",
            0.040675200000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRUZZHT128F93229AF",
            0.039422199999999998
        ],
        [
            "TRLSIHL128F429AF18",
            0.039002099999999998
        ],
        [
            "TRGETCK128F1460DB1",
            0.038499499999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRSXXNU128F428AEF2",
            0.038303799999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRFZXSY128F9330D9F",
            0.037855199999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRPHFYF128F92F27FA",
            0.037772100000000003
        ],
        [
            "TRNRHSL128F9337B55",
            0.036998000000000003
        ],
        [
            "TRPTGNZ128F421A56B",
            0.036713099999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRPAASI128F9337B6E",
            0.036410499999999998
        ],
        [
            "TRGCROO128F93431C4",
            0.035754300000000003
        ],
        [
            "TRCUHZL128F4235446",
            0.034968699999999998
        ],
        [
            "TRDPOTJ128F429AF0C",
            0.034860500000000003
        ],
        [
            "TROZUXM128F42790A2",
            0.0346483
        ],
        [
            "TRJVLOQ128F9345A82",
            0.034547799999999997
        ],
        [
            "TRQTFRP128F145FC1E",
            0.033934600000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRQEWHR128F421A3F5",
            0.032314599999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRNTPJA128F4265039",
            0.030702900000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRDGXWY12903CF52BD",
            0.030292300000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRBLEMZ128F93102D0",
            0.029224300000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRBUUYO128F421A405",
            0.028448500000000002
        ],
        [
            "TREVBDI12903CED7E6",
            0.0279674
        ],
        [
            "TRKREBF128F429B317",
            0.0258321
        ],
        [
            "TRZBYPR128F4233A8D",
            0.025655000000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRTAZUQ12903CFEA78",
            0.024545399999999998
        ],
        [
            "TRAIPRO128F429AE69",
            0.024304699999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRTTVUZ128F92FADD3",
            0.023320899999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRUYEJI128F4265041",
            0.022173700000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRAXVGT128F9344507",
            0.0213992
        ],
        [
            "TRJJBLH128F4260DA1",
            0.0175365
        ],
        [
            "TRAMCWR128F4233F7F",
            0.0161158
        ],
        [
            "TRXBLME128F424330F",
            0.015760900000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRMUQXM128F4260D99",
            0.015696000000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRHRZBJ128EF345514",
            0.0156951
        ],
        [
            "TRJXIBT128F42454DB",
            0.014519199999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRTHPOY128F9345AA5",
            0.0137264
        ],
        [
            "TRRFGJU128F933B2E6",
            0.0012336199999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRMYJUA128F428A590",
            0.00123149
        ],
        [
            "TRNMVTE128F933B2EC",
            0.00122703
        ],
        [
            "TRYALZM128F1483C7D",
            0.0012245299999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRZVEJU128F4234F4E",
            0.00121805
        ],
        [
            "TRQAZDO128F145639F",
            0.0012166600000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRJXNJM12903CF57ED",
            0.0012155
        ],
        [
            "TRVAOGO128F427C9D6",
            0.00120951
        ],
        [
            "TRZMZDS128F422843B",
            0.0012065000000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRXIEOF12903CE8212",
            0.0012058699999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRPVVUG128F42A36AA",
            0.0012057599999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRXGVXS128F428AA5C",
            0.0012019400000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRUBOGF128E078A5B9",
            0.0012017900000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRITZSB128F4277CC2",
            0.0012014
        ],
        [
            "TRGHPHX128F9343544",
            0.0011975600000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRUKWPE128F428114F",
            0.00119666
        ],
        [
            "TROBGRB128F93229AB",
            0.0011964199999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRGKTMW12903CFAE65",
            0.00119637
        ]
    ],
    "tags":[
        [
            "punk rock",
            "100"
        ],
        [
            "punk",
            "60"
        ]
    ],
    "track_id":"TRAAAFD128F92F423A",
    "title":"Face the Ashes"
}
```

**File_2**

```
{
    "artist":"CLP",
    "timestamp":"2011-08-02 06:36:59.879759",
    "similars":[

    ],
    "tags":[

    ],
    "track_id":"TRAAAVG12903CFA543",
    "title":"Insatiable (Instrumental Version)"
}
```

I wrote a Python script to combine them. I added a new line and a comma after each record.

```
import glob

read_files = glob.glob("*.json")

with open("merged_file.json", "wb") as outfile:
     for f in read_files:
          with open(f, "rb") as infile:
               outfile.write(infile.read())
               outfile.write(',\n')
```

The output from the merge file is:

```
    {
    "artist":"Gob",
    "timestamp":"2011-08-09 01:59:41.352247",
    "similars":[
        [
            "TRTOVWD128F92F4227",
            1
        ],
        [
            "TRUXNUD128F92F41D0",
            0.97294099999999994
        ],
        [
            "TRNNOJO128F42992E9",
            0.073926900000000004
        ],
        [
            "TRGZHTT128F423B2A4",
            0.068387699999999996
        ],
        [
            "TRGYKYD128F42625F6",
            0.065579700000000005
        ],
        [
            "TRGIWHY128F42625F5",
            0.064063700000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRJCJTX128F930CACE",
            0.063140100000000005
        ],
        [
            "TRMYNWT128F426254B",
            0.0613825
        ],
        [
            "TRRQOJI128F428C865",
            0.061121599999999998
        ],
        [
            "TRBNYHM128F428A569",
            0.061121599999999998
        ],
        [
            "TRDLOYE128F4241E72",
            0.060951900000000003
        ],
        [
            "TRNRVEW12903CBA24F",
            0.060332700000000003
        ],
        [
            "TRKKIPG12903CBA083",
            0.060155
        ],
        [
            "TRZHTGP128F428A63B",
            0.059873599999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRKQSGZ128F428A851",
            0.059873599999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRTOPDF128F42AD88A",
            0.059687799999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRIWOPM128F4241E53",
            0.058958900000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRCCJUW128F14652DB",
            0.057935
        ],
        [
            "TRERDDF128F428ECC4",
            0.057566600000000002
        ],
        [
            "TROKWNN128F421A3D8",
            0.057379800000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRWGOOK128F42AE765",
            0.057125000000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRFMNKP128F428ADC0",
            0.056875099999999998
        ],
        [
            "TRDMLZT128F42A01A8",
            0.055808900000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRGCJVM128E0780E48",
            0.0547389
        ],
        [
            "TRRXGAY128F14652D7",
            0.0538065
        ],
        [
            "TRIPEHH128F1462DFF",
            0.052843000000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRDUOIP128F147D5A7",
            0.051851500000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRZCHHD12903CC80A1",
            0.051251699999999997
        ],
        [
            "TRFDDQS128F426243F",
            0.051018300000000003
        ],
        [
            "TRZDKAR128F42591B8",
            0.050740899999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRDVXUG128F1456CBF",
            0.050486299999999998
        ],
        [
            "TRULRYN128F145FC1C",
            0.050219800000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRMOWIA128F425CE0F",
            0.049977500000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRUVPMZ128F42B6DF3",
            0.049762000000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRSBDWW128F4262666",
            0.049643699999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRKPHWQ128F4264F8C",
            0.0495173
        ],
        [
            "TRBBLXU128F42623A1",
            0.049416700000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRJKLLM128F1456C57",
            0.049001599999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRSAAEI128F4216C24",
            0.048813500000000003
        ],
        [
            "TRFXICT128F4264F8A",
            0.048776199999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRINVLH12903CBE5A1",
            0.048334500000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRMUUJR128F4262475",
            0.048306500000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRTORTD128F1456AFA",
            0.0468265
        ],
        [
            "TRECUJO12903CA7120",
            0.046065599999999998
        ],
        [
            "TRXIRBQ128F93431BB",
            0.0456938
        ],
        [
            "TRFDDVK128F42B6DF0",
            0.045623799999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRSRGPM128F421A30B",
            0.043976800000000003
        ],
        [
            "TRVUPPR128F429507D",
            0.042872500000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRMHCZC128F428A4CD",
            0.040675200000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRUFDRV128F4262352",
            0.040675200000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRUZZHT128F93229AF",
            0.039422199999999998
        ],
        [
            "TRLSIHL128F429AF18",
            0.039002099999999998
        ],
        [
            "TRGETCK128F1460DB1",
            0.038499499999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRSXXNU128F428AEF2",
            0.038303799999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRFZXSY128F9330D9F",
            0.037855199999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRPHFYF128F92F27FA",
            0.037772100000000003
        ],
        [
            "TRNRHSL128F9337B55",
            0.036998000000000003
        ],
        [
            "TRPTGNZ128F421A56B",
            0.036713099999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRPAASI128F9337B6E",
            0.036410499999999998
        ],
        [
            "TRGCROO128F93431C4",
            0.035754300000000003
        ],
        [
            "TRCUHZL128F4235446",
            0.034968699999999998
        ],
        [
            "TRDPOTJ128F429AF0C",
            0.034860500000000003
        ],
        [
            "TROZUXM128F42790A2",
            0.0346483
        ],
        [
            "TRJVLOQ128F9345A82",
            0.034547799999999997
        ],
        [
            "TRQTFRP128F145FC1E",
            0.033934600000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRQEWHR128F421A3F5",
            0.032314599999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRNTPJA128F4265039",
            0.030702900000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRDGXWY12903CF52BD",
            0.030292300000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRBLEMZ128F93102D0",
            0.029224300000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRBUUYO128F421A405",
            0.028448500000000002
        ],
        [
            "TREVBDI12903CED7E6",
            0.0279674
        ],
        [
            "TRKREBF128F429B317",
            0.0258321
        ],
        [
            "TRZBYPR128F4233A8D",
            0.025655000000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRTAZUQ12903CFEA78",
            0.024545399999999998
        ],
        [
            "TRAIPRO128F429AE69",
            0.024304699999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRTTVUZ128F92FADD3",
            0.023320899999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRUYEJI128F4265041",
            0.022173700000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRAXVGT128F9344507",
            0.0213992
        ],
        [
            "TRJJBLH128F4260DA1",
            0.0175365
        ],
        [
            "TRAMCWR128F4233F7F",
            0.0161158
        ],
        [
            "TRXBLME128F424330F",
            0.015760900000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRMUQXM128F4260D99",
            0.015696000000000002
        ],
        [
            "TRHRZBJ128EF345514",
            0.0156951
        ],
        [
            "TRJXIBT128F42454DB",
            0.014519199999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRTHPOY128F9345AA5",
            0.0137264
        ],
        [
            "TRRFGJU128F933B2E6",
            0.0012336199999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRMYJUA128F428A590",
            0.00123149
        ],
        [
            "TRNMVTE128F933B2EC",
            0.00122703
        ],
        [
            "TRYALZM128F1483C7D",
            0.0012245299999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRZVEJU128F4234F4E",
            0.00121805
        ],
        [
            "TRQAZDO128F145639F",
            0.0012166600000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRJXNJM12903CF57ED",
            0.0012155
        ],
        [
            "TRVAOGO128F427C9D6",
            0.00120951
        ],
        [
            "TRZMZDS128F422843B",
            0.0012065000000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRXIEOF12903CE8212",
            0.0012058699999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRPVVUG128F42A36AA",
            0.0012057599999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRXGVXS128F428AA5C",
            0.0012019400000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRUBOGF128E078A5B9",
            0.0012017900000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRITZSB128F4277CC2",
            0.0012014
        ],
        [
            "TRGHPHX128F9343544",
            0.0011975600000000001
        ],
        [
            "TRUKWPE128F428114F",
            0.00119666
        ],
        [
            "TROBGRB128F93229AB",
            0.0011964199999999999
        ],
        [
            "TRGKTMW12903CFAE65",
            0.00119637
        ]
    ],
    "tags":[
        [
            "punk rock",
            "100"
        ],
        [
            "punk",
            "60"
        ]
    ],
    "track_id":"TRAAAFD128F92F423A",
    "title":"Face the Ashes"
},
{
    "artist":"CLP",
    "timestamp":"2011-08-02 06:36:59.879759",
    "similars":[

    ],
    "tags":[

    ],
    "track_id":"TRAAAVG12903CFA543",
    "title":"Insatiable (Instrumental Version)"
}
```

When I validate these records using JSON Lint (http://jsonlint.com/), it tells me that the file is broken and not a valid JSON. even after spending quite sometime, I am not able to figure out what is going wrong with the merging. It would be helpful is anyone has any thoughts on this.

Comment: You are writing *two separate JSON strings* to one file. As a whole, that's not valid JSON, no. What is your goal here; what should the resulting JSON file represent? A list of those objects?

Comment: In fact it's a list of json records

Comment: Oops...I can't believe how naive I sounded! I completely forgot about the Python json module...gonna get a coffee right away...and thanks everyone for waking me up..:-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can't just concatenate two JSON strings to make [valid JSON](https://www.json.org/) (or combine them by tacking `',\n'` to the end of each). 
Instead, you could combine the two (as Python objects) into a Python list, then use [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) to write it to a file as JSON:

```
import json
import glob

result = []
for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
    with open(f, "rb") as infile:
        result.append(json.load(infile))

with open("merged_file.json", "wb") as outfile:
     json.dump(result, outfile)
```

---

If you wanted to do it without the (unnecesssary) intermediate step of parsing each JSON file, you could merge them into a list like this:

```
import glob

read_files = glob.glob("*.json")
with open("merged_file.json", "wb") as outfile:
    outfile.write('[{}]'.format(
        ','.join([open(f, "rb").read() for f in read_files])))
```

Comment: I noticed that the first part of your answer and Martijn Pieters' answer both use `open(f,"rb")` followed by `json.load()` whereas the second half of your answer uses `open(f, "rb").read()`.  Is there any advantage to one over the other?

Answer (score 10):

There is a module called `jsonmerge` which merges dictionaries. It can be used very simple by just providing two dictionaries  or you can define schema's that described how to merge, like instead of  overwriting same key's, automatically create a list and append to it.

```
base = {
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": [ "one" ],
}
head = {
    "bar": [ "two" ],
    "baz": "Hello, world!"
}

from  jsonmerge import merge
result = merge(base, head)
print(result)
>>> {'foo': 1, 'bar': ['two'], 'baz': 'Hello, world!'}
```

More examples with complex rules: https://pypi.org/project/jsonmerge/#description

Comment: Can you provide an example where the keys do not overwrite the values when they're the same? In the OP's question, the values are not overridden in the desired results.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to produce a JSON *list* of those objects, you are missing opening `[` and closing `]` brackets here, and will have written one comma too many.

It'll be easier to have Python decode the objects, then write the output as a new JSON list:

```
import json
import glob

read_files = glob.glob("*.json")
output_list = []

for f in read_files:
    with open(f, "rb") as infile:
        output_list.append(json.load(infile))

with open("merged_file.json", "wb") as outfile:
    json.dump(output_list, outfile)
```

Comment: I had to change `open("...", "wb")` to `open("...", "w")` to make it work for me, which is I think what you recommended here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153768/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-saving-json-data-in-pyth (unless I misunderstood?)

Answer (score 3):

**Python solution:**

You have file1.json and file2.json files.

*Each file has structure:*

```
[{"key1": "value1"}] - (in file1)
[{"key2": "value2"}] - (in file2)
```

*And your goal to merge them and get next view:*

```
[{"key1": "value1"},
 {"key2": "value2"}]
```

Code:

```
import glob
glob_data = []
for file in glob.glob('../../file*.json'):
    with open(file) as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)

        i = 0
        while i < len(data):
            glob_data.append(data[i])
            i += 1

with open('../../finalFile.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(glob_data, f, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your generated JSON isn't valid. You end up with something like:

```
{...}, {...}
```

which, of course, is not valid.

If you want to go with your approach, you should remove the last `}` and the first `{` from the new file, and then merge them (you still have to be sure that the JSON files you want to merge are in a valid format).

I suggest I use the `json` module for what you need to achieve, it is cleaner.