# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' – Saving JSON data in Python

Tags: python, json, typeerror

I am getting data from twitter in json format and storing the same in a file.

```
consumer_key = 'Consumer KEY'
consumer_secret = 'Secret'
access_token = 'Token'
access_secret = 'Access Secret'

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

os.chdir('Path')
file = open('TwData.json','wb')

for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).items(15):
    simplejson.dump(status._json,file,sort_keys = True)
file.close
```

But I am getting the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/Users/abc/anaconda/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 180, in dump
    fp.write(chunk)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: This code cannot generate this error

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ: sure it can.

Comment: Why did you open the file in binary mode? You are also not actually *calling* the `file.close()` method, that line is rather redundant as it stands.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [`json.dump()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump):

> The json module always produces str objects, not bytes objects. Therefore, `fp.write()` must support str input.

You opened the file in binary mode. Don't do that, remove the `b` from the file mode:

```
file = open('TwData.json','w')
```

It's better to use an absolute path rather than change the working directory, and if you used the file as a context manager (with the `with` statement), it'll be automatically closed for you when the block is done. That helps avoid errors like forgetting to actually call the `file.close()` method.

And if you are going to write multiple JSON documents to the file, at least put a *newline* between each document, making it a [JSON lines file](http://jsonlines.org/); this is [much easier to parse again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451431/loading-and-parsing-a-json-file-with-multiple-json-objects-in-python) later on:

```
with open('Path/TWData.json', 'w') as file:    
    for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).items(15):
        json.dump(status._json, file, sort_keys=True)
        file.write('\n')
```

Alternatively, put everything into a top-level object like mapping or list, and write that *single* object to the file to create a valid JSON document.

Comment: What if we actually *want* to store in a binary file?

Comment: @user32882 then use `json.dumps()` to produce a string, and then encode that string to bytes. Or wrap your binary file object in a [`TextIOWrapper` instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper), and pass that wrapper to `json.dump()`. You probably want to set `write_through=True` and don’t forget to call [`.detach()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.detach) once done.

Answer (score 1):

*Don't* store separate json objects. Append each one to a list, and then dump at once.

```
with open('TwData.json','w') as file:    
    data = []
    for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).items(15):
        data.append(status._json)

    simplejson.dump(data, file, sort_keys=True)
```

Should also note here that you shouldn't open the file in binary mode if you want to write text to it.

Comment: very useful..appreciate it

Comment: my bad,  i wasnt aware about that..wanted to accept both of these, but since i had accepted Martjin's earlier, its not letting me accept yours..still both are equally useful for me..