# Creating training data by training more than one files

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

I am trying to create training data for my intelligent chatbot. Each time a user logs into the webpage he/she could enter data to the file. These file is used to create training data. I don't have an idea that if there are more than one file how will I take data from all files and create a training data.

Below is the I used for training:

```
# things we need for NLP
import nltk
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

# things we need for Tensorflow
import numpy as np
import tflearn
import tensorflow as tf
import random
import scipy

# import our chat-bot intents file
import json
with open('sales.json') as json_data:
    intents = json.load(json_data)
words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_words = ['?']
# loop through each sentence in our intents patterns
for intent in intents['intents']:
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        # tokenize each word in the sentence
        w = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        # add to our words list
        words.extend(w)
        # add to documents in our corpus
        documents.append((w, intent['tag']))
        # add to our classes list
        if intent['tag'] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent['tag'])
# stem and lower each word and remove duplicates
words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w not in ignore_words]
words = sorted(list(set(words)))

# remove duplicates
classes = sorted(list(set(classes)))
print (len(documents), "documents")
print (len(classes), "classes", classes)
print (len(words), "unique stemmed words", words)

# create our training data
training = []
output = []
# create an empty array for our output
output_empty = [0] * len(classes)

# training set, bag of words for each sentence
for doc in documents:
    # initialize our bag of words
    bag = []
    # list of tokenized words for the pattern
    pattern_words = doc[0]
    # stem each word
    pattern_words = [stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for word in pattern_words]
    # create our bag of words array
    for w in words:
        bag.append(1) if w in pattern_words else bag.append(0)


    # output is a '0' for each tag and '1' for current tag
    output_row = list(output_empty)
    output_row[classes.index(doc[1])] = 1

    training.append([bag, output_row])

# shuffle our features and turn into np.array
random.shuffle(training)
training = np.array(training)

# create train and test lists
train_x = list(training[:,0])
train_y = list(training[:,1])

# reset underlying graph data
tf.reset_default_graph()
# Build neural network
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(train_x[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)

# Define model and setup tensorboard
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_dir='tflearn_logs')
# Start training (apply gradient descent algorithm)
model.fit(train_x, train_y, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
model.save('model.tflearn')

import pickle
pickle.dump( {'words':words, 'classes':classes, 'train_x':train_x, 'train_y':train_y}, open( "training_data", "wb" ) )
```

Here I have created training data by using only one json file, however, if there are more than one file, how can I use all files to create training data.

Comment: You shouldn't create a new question, but edit the [one you've already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53492597/train-chat-bot-by-appending-data-to-json-file). Also, it seems that your problem has nothing to do with chatbots or tensorflow, but rather how to merge json files in python.

Comment: Yes , i need to merge multiple json files - @Lescurel

Comment: I don't know about your specific problem, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520542/issue-with-merging-multiple-json-files-in-python) could help you.