# Joining multiple json files using python

Tags: python, json, join

I am new to JSON, never used python packages to manipulate JSON files. I have 10 JSON files that I would like to merge into one using python.

Each of 10 files has the exact same structure and has about 50,000 entries

Example:

File one

```
{"tracking_code":"21703238","from_country":"FR","to_country":"FR","amount":3.23}
...
```

Example: File two

```
{"tracking_code":"41545695","from_country":"FR","to_country":"FR","amount":2.9}
...
```

Desired output would simply be:

```
{"tracking_code":"21703238","from_country":"FR","to_country":"FR","amount":3.23}
{"tracking_code":"41545695","from_country":"FR","to_country":"FR","amount":2.9}
```

The second part of my questions would be this - how would I join JSON files based on one key? I would like to join these 2 files by "tracking_code", the output file would simply add '"amount":3.23' to the first file.

Example: File one:

```
{"tracking_code":"29285908","from_country":"FR","to_country":"FR",
"package_type_id":10,"transaction_id":172238850,
"shipping_label_created":"2018-09-25 18:40:52"}
```

Example: File two

```
{"tracking_code":"29285908","from_country":"FR","to_country":"FR","amount":3.23}
```

Desired output:

```
{"tracking_code":"29285908","from_country":"FR","to_country":"FR",
"package_type_id":10,"transaction_id":172238850,
"shipping_label_created":"2018-09-25 18:40:52","amount":3.23}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with merging multiple JSON files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520542/issue-with-merging-multiple-json-files-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `json.loads()` (that "converts" json to python dictionary), you can merge them using a similar function :

```
def dict_merge(dict1, dict2): 
    return(dict2.update(dict1))
```

and then use `json.dumps()` to serialize the resulting dictionary to json.

**Other solution :**

you can also use `json-merger` (installation via `pip install json-merger`)

Comment: How would I go if I have 10 files? Function with 10 inputs would look ugly, I would assume loop over files?

Comment: indeed, you would have to loop over files

Comment: `json-merger` usage doc : https://pythonhosted.org/json-merger/usage.html